# .push breaking in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following loop that adds an object to an array if certain criteria are met.

```
var form = $('form[id^="product-form"]'),
    submit_button = $('#add-to-cart'),
    attr_fields = $('.additional input[type=text]'),
    attr_fields_default = {};
// Get the default values for each attribute field and place into an obj
attr_fields.each(function () {
    var field = $(this),
        field_id = field.attr('id'),
        field_val = field.val();
    attr_fields_default[field_id] = field_val;
});
var extra_attr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < attr_fields.length; i++) {
    var _field = $(attr_fields[i]);
    if (_field.val() != attr_fields_default[_field.attr('id')]) {
        var jsonStr = {
            'add': _field.attr('id'),
            'quantity': 1
        };
        extra_attr.push(jsonStr);
        console.log(jsonStr);
    } else {
        _field.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('None');
    }
}
console.log(extra_attr);
```

The code works perfectly until the last loop, although console.log( jsonStr ) outputs the last object as expected, console.log( extra_attr ) does not. It does not push the last item into the array. I even tried changing jsonStr to a dummy string 'test' and i still get the same result.

Here is a screenshot of my chrome developer console http://cl.ly/GdHw

I should also note that I originally tried to use .each() to loop through the selectors with the exact same results

```
         attr_fields
        .each(function(){
          if ( $(this).val() != attr_fields_default[ $(this).attr('id') ] ) {
            var jsonStr = {'add': $(this).attr('id'), 'quantity': 1};
            extra_attr.push( jsonStr );
            console.log( jsonStr );
          } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('None');
          }
```

Comment: Create a minimal test-case (e.g. only the last part with some simulated data that shows the problem) and post a jsfiddle. Also make sure to try in different browsers. Chrome has a funny habit of, at least historically, doing funky console.log caching.

Comment: why are you running two loops when you can do it in one? are thse loops in separate functions?

Comment: Yes they are in two different functions. The later is in a under a submit event.

Comment: Based on the code you provided (and the assumption that the second loop is executed at a later time, i.e. after the user enters the values) I see nothing wrong. Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4BDc/). As far as I can tell it works perfectly (just enter some values in the fields, click the button and check the console).

Comment: The problem was with an asynchronous call later in the code that was using .pop() to grab the last element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with an asynchronous call later in the code that was using .pop() to grab the last element